# Multisite Network menu links not updating

Tags: multisite, redirect, options, wp-config

I recently made a copy of my live Multisite network and moved it to a domain for testing. For some reason the links in the "Network Admin" menu are not updating to the new testing domain. These links reside under:

My Sites -> Network Admin -> Dashboard/Sites/Users etc..

I've gone through the database, htaccess files and config files but I'm not sure where the links to the old site are coming from. I can go through each site individually and browser through pages and plugins, etc but when I try to go the Network admin there is a 302 redirect to the old domain. It's very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pat J's answer is correct but left out one important step.

In wp-config.php the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE constant must be updated or the behavior that brandozz explains will occur.

***When updating domains for a WordPress Multisite:***

1. Update the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE constant in wp-config.php

   define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'my-domain-name.com');
2. In DB table named "wp_sitemeta" update "siteurl" meta key
3. In DB tables named "wp_{blog_id}_options" update "siteurl" and "home" meta keys
4. Search for remaining links to update in post content with phpMyAdmin or MySQL command line. *Be careful when changing links in JSON or serialized arrays.*

Answer (score 0):

Each site will have a couple of options in the `wp_{blog_id}_options` table, named `siteurl` and `home`. Additionally, there will be at least `siteurl` in the `wp_sitemeta` table, which will define the `siteurl` for your Multisite network's root site.

Your best bet is probably to change all these values to the new server's URL.

There's a bit of information on the [Database Description Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Multisite_Table_Overview) -- mostly about the schema -- but most of my knowledge of this comes from a combination of Google and trying things out.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone through the options tables for each blog and didn't see any references to the old site. I replaced all instances of the old url using a Search & Replace plugin but the old links are still there. Strange that it's actually a 302 redirect.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you turn off all your plugins?

Comment: I haven't tried that...problem is I can't get to the Network Admin -> Plugins section on the site because of this issue. Do you suggest I deactivate on a per site basis?

Comment: You could try installing [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) on your local dev machine, and then use something like `wp plugin deactivate --network --all`.